# Recurrent auto-sync of assets from one S3 bucket to another in separate account

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-datasync

**The problem**:
I have an old S3 bucket: **bucket A** and a new S3 bucket: **bucket B**. These buckets are in separate accounts. Up until now, I have been serving assets from **bucket A**. Moving forward, I want to serve assets from **bucket B**. I must still support pushing to **bucket A**. However, those assets pushed to **bucket A** must be retrievable from **bucket B**.

**Possible solutions**:
On every new push to **bucket A** ([PutObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_PutObject.html)), I must sync that object from **bucket A** to **bucket B**. As I understand it, there are two ways to achieve this:

1. [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)
2. [Using DataSync](https://aws.amazon.com/datasync) `<-- preferred solution`

**Issue with solution 2**:
I have a feeling the path using DataSync will be less complex. However, it's not clear to me how to accomplish this, or if it is even possible. The examples I see in the documentation (granted there is a lot to sift through) are not quite the same as this use-case. In the console, it does not seem to allow a task across multiple AWS accounts.

The disconnect I'm seeing here is, the documentation implies it is possible. However, when you navigate to [DataSync Locations in the AWS Console](https://us-west-2.console.aws.amazon.com/datasync/home?region=us-west-2#/locations), there is only the option to add locations in your AWS accounts S3 bucket list.

Comment: Why is S3 object replication not an option? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @MarkB. This was kind of an obvious choice I over looked. However, I set it up and nothing is happening. I enabled logs/metrics, but nothing is coming through on the charts. And none of the objects are being pushed through. I have zero insight as to why it is failing. I believe my IAM policy on the dest bucket is correct because when setting up the replication rule, it was able to detect the bucket had versioning. All I see on the object is "FAILED" under replication status. Any thoughts on how to debug this?

Comment: S3 replication can take up to 15 min.